# CORS HTTPS-to-HTTP webservice in Chrome Extension

Tags: web-services, http, google-chrome-extension, https, cors

I am writing a 'Content Script' based extension for Chrome that works on GMail (HTTPS). It needs to access a web service on our website, which is currently on HTTP only. Other than getting an SSL, is there any alternative to get an AJAX GET/POST call working between these two?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

But be aware that without https someone can see and change everything your extension send or receive with your website.

You should implement https as soon as possible to avoid any security issue.

Comment: Are you referring to setting permissions? It still throws an error.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:9010/?email=user%40domain.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.